# How to make move-to-column with force option in Emacs insert spaces instead of tabs and spaces

Tags: emacs, elisp

When using `(move-to-column col t)` with column argument larger than `end-of-line` Emacs inserts a combination of spaces and tabs, depending on whether `col` ends on a tab stop or not.

How can I make it insert only spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`indent-tabs-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Indent-Tabs-Mode.html) to `nil`, either using [`setq-default`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Default-Value.html):

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

or [`customize`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html):

```
(custom-set-variables '(indent-tabs-mode nil))
```